# error: invalid operands to binary -

Tags: c

This piece of code is giving the error `error: invalid operands to binary -`:

```
if(memcmp(params , DEV_SERVICE_DISCOVERY , strlen(DEV_SERVICE_DISCOVERY)) == 0)
{
    UINT8 *yes_no;

    params = XSH_UtilFindNextToken(params);
    yes_no = XSH_UtilFindNextToken(params);

    params[yes_no - params - 1] = '\0';

    rc = AppTest_ServiceDiscovery(params, yes_no , strlen(yes_no), pOut);
}
```

I changed `UINT8 *yes_no` to `char *yes_no` and it got resolved. But didn't get why error was coming and why it got resolved. Please explain the issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: not a duplicate: it is nonsense to add pointers, but substract them is useful to compute an offset if the pointer belongs the same array

Comment: What is the type of `params`? I'm guessing it's `char *`. If so that explains it. Pointer subtraction requires the pointers to be of the same type.

Comment: Yes param is of char *.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When subtracting two pointers, they must be of the same type.  This is because pointer arithmetic in C is based on the size of the pointees, so for example if you subtract `char*` from `int*` you have a 1-byte object and a 4-byte object, and so there is no way for the compiler to know whether the result should be in 1-byte units or 4-byte units.

I realize your two pointees are both single bytes, but it's still not allowed in standard C (which makes no assumptions that objects of different types would be stored in the same area, etc.).